# Resize List row in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a `List` and each row in the list has a `.tapAction` that toggle's it's `collapsed` state property. When `collapsed` is false, the row  is expanded and displays more detailed information.

The problem I'm having is that when a row is expanded, the view inside the row changes it's height but the row remains the same height. This causes the row's contents to sometimes expand outside of the row.

[image: preview of rows contents outside of row]

Is anyone else having this issue? Is there another way of resizing a row besides resizing it's contents?

Comment: Could you post some code. Also check this related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56802510/7786555